# How to seperate Query to another class/file?

Tags: php, symfony

I created a seperate class for one of my DataTables (lets say `MyTableType`). Inside `ORMAdapter` I've created a custom query, which gets quite long and complicated. This is why I'd like to seperate it from the code that's responsible for creating a table itself and move it into some other class (like `MyTableQuery`).

I am using Symfony 4.2 and omines/datatables-bundle bundle.

What should that class for queries return? And what's the best way then to get the returned query in `MyTableType`?

```
class MyTableType implements DataTableTypeInterface
{
    public function configure(DataTable $dataTable, array $options)
    {
        $request = $options['request'];

        $dataTable
            ->add('id',
                NumberColumn::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'ID',
                    'globalSearchable' => false
                )
            )

Some more columns

->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class,
                array(
                    'entity' => MyEntity::class,
                    'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) use ($request)
                    { 
                        //Long query I'd prefer to get from somewhere else
                    }
                )
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

Inside my `query` option I'd like to get the return from that custom class `MyTypeQuery`. It'd make `MyTableType` class much cleaner. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if this is the best solution, but what I've done is:

```
* Pass Doctrine Manager to Table Building class

* Inside my query option pass $builder into repository and build a query on top passed variable.
  And it works.
```

```
class MyTableType implements DataTableTypeInterface
{
    public function configure(DataTable $dataTable, array $options)
    {
        $request = $options['request'];
        $em = $options['entityManager'];

        $dataTable
            ->add('id',
                NumberColumn::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'ID',
                    'globalSearchable' => false
                )
            )

... Some more columns ...

->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class,
                array(
                    'entity' => MyEntity::class,
                    'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) use ($request, $em)
                    { $em->getRepository(MyClass::class)->find($request, $builder) }
                )
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

Inside my repository I return passed QueryBuilder variable and that's all.